# How can I add a CSS class to the button that is clicked among multiple buttons using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My motive is when someone will click on a particular button then will show the particular cards and will add a class named `category_btn_active` that clicked. Suppose `Services` will be clicked then the `service cards` will be shown. Here the filtering is working well, the problem is here `$(this).addClass('category_btn_active').siblings().removeClass('category_btn_active')`. The `category_btn_active` class adds when clicked but when I clicked another button it stays in both buttons. I want the class will be added to just the last clicked button. Where is the problem? give a relevant solution...

***index.html:***

```
<li><a href="#!" class="category_btn category_btn_active" data-filter="Services">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#!" class="category_btn" data-filter="Static">Static Website</a></li>


<div class="Services service_itembox">
    <img src="Assets/pic-1.jpg" alt="service image">
</div>

<div class="Static service_itembox">
    <img src="Assets/pic-2.jpg" alt="service image">
</div>
```

***index.js:***

```
$(function () {
    $(".category_btn").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('category_btn_active').siblings().removeClass('category_btn_active')

        const value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        if(value == "Services"){
            $('.service_itembox').show('slow');
        }else{
            $('.service_itembox').not('.'+value).hide('slow');
            $('.service_itembox').filter('.'+value).show('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

***style.css:***

```
.category_btn_active{
    color: white;
    border-color:gray;
    border-style:solid ;
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
    background-color: #019587;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: `.siblings()` will get all sibling elements (same level). Since your anchors are stand-alone and wrapped in an `li`, siblings will return no elements, so it's not doing what you think it will. Best solution is to use a selector for all the elements with `className` `category_btn` and remove the desired `className`

Comment: Your anchor tags (`<a>`) don't have siblings. Their parent `<li>` elements do.

Comment: @RyanWilson the problem I noticed is when "services" unclicked at the period all card shows,, which I don't want. I just want just will be shown service-related cards when it's active as primary period.

Comment: @Marc ..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most elegant way to do this, but it illustrates use of `parent()` and `sibling()`, which you were struggling with:

https://jsfiddle.net/v5fg3qwh/2/

```
$(function () {
    $(".category_btn").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('category_btn_active').parent().siblings().find("a.category_btn").removeClass('category_btn_active')

        const value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $(`.${value}.service_itembox`).show('slow');
        $(`.service_itembox`).not('.'+value).hide('slow');
        $(`.service_itembox`).filter('.'+value).show('slow');
    });
});
```

Note that I removed your `if/else` because you don't need it. Your classes and JS logic are defined in such a way that you can specify your intent w/out those conditionals.

I also defaulted one of your images to be `hidden` at initialization, which I assume is what you'd want:

```
div.Static.service_itembox {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: In the primary stage, the "services" button will be active, and all cards of the service category will be shown.  Here "service" Button is active at the initial stage and it's okay, but the problem is showing all category cards instead of just the "service" category cards.

Comment: @Mossaddak, I cannot tell what you want to accomplish, or if there's a question in your comment. But I put together that JSFiddle, which you are welcome to experiment with, save your own copy of, and use to further explain your issue, possibly in the *original question* so it's clear what you're asking. If you don't have further questions, feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: ,, The initial stage "Services" section will be active, and all the card of service categories will be shown. But here when the "Service" section is active showing all the categories cards, that I don't want. I want at the initial stage the "Service" category will be active, and when a user will click another category's button then that particular section or cards will be shown. As well the previous section will be off.

Comment: The code I gave you initializes by showing the "Services" `service_itembox`. When you click "Static," it hides the Services `service_itembox` and shows the Static `service_itembox`. When you click back to Services, it hides Static `service_itembox` and shows Services `service_itembox`. How is that different from what you're describing? I think I've done all I know how to do for you at this point. Perhaps someone else can figure out what you want.